# Put gradiant to show cell on my UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, shadow

I want to put a shadow in the footer and the header of my UITableview. I found some examples of putting a shadow under the header, but I want to replace the header (and footer) with a gradiant.

Here is an example:

[image: http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/6494/picpd.png]

thx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try thise one http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients

Answer (score 0):

I have some example code on my github for this very thing: [meek apps/FancyTableView](https://github.com/meekapps/FancyTableView)